# Android - Looking for help with force close on application

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, java

I am using Eclipse to write the program.  I have gotten rid of the errors, and have completely compiled the code and when it launches in the emulator, it forces close. I have zipped the workspace so maybe someone can grab it and load it to see if they are able to see why its bombing out? deckertdesigns.com/Android/Todo_List.zip any help again, would be greatly appreciated. I feel once over this hump I will have some better knowledge in troubleshooting, just wish the debugger was catching this...

08-29 17:43:45.273: DEBUG/SntpClient(73): request time failed: java.net.SocketException:

Address family not supported by protocol

08-29 17:44:41.433: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(357): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

08-29 17:44:41.433: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(357): CheckJNI is ON

08-29 17:44:41.852: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(357): --- registering native functions ---

08-29 17:44:43.293: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(357): Shutting down VM

08-29 17:44:43.313: INFO/AndroidRuntime(357): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

08-29 17:44:43.323: DEBUG/dalvikvm(357): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

08-29 17:44:44.083: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(365): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

08-29 17:44:44.083: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(365): CheckJNI is ON

08-29 17:44:44.403: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(365): --- registering native functions ---

08-29 17:44:45.573: INFO/ActivityManager(73): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.a8a.todolist/.ToDoList }

08-29 17:44:45.683: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(365): Shutting down VM

08-29 17:44:45.713: DEBUG/dalvikvm(365): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

08-29 17:44:45.773: INFO/AndroidRuntime(365): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

08-29 17:44:45.843: INFO/ActivityManager(73): Start proc com.a8a.todolist for activity com.a8a.todolist/.ToDoList: pid=372 uid=10032 gids={1015}

08-29 17:44:47.013: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(372): Shutting down VM

08-29 17:44:47.013: WARN/dalvikvm(372): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.a8a.todolist/com.a8a.todolist.ToDoList} did not call through to super.onCreate()

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

08-29 17:44:47.043: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

08-29 17:44:47.063: WARN/ActivityManager(73):   Force finishing activity com.a8a.todolist/.ToDoList

08-29 17:44:47.243: DEBUG/dalvikvm(73): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7176 objects / 434168 bytes in 169ms

08-29 17:44:47.633: WARN/ActivityManager(73): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43fc9668 com.a8a.todolist/.ToDoList}

08-29 17:44:53.253: INFO/Process(372): Sending signal. PID: 372 SIG: 9

08-29 17:44:53.285: INFO/ActivityManager(73): Process com.a8a.todolist (pid 372) has died.

08-29 17:44:53.323: WARN/InputManagerService(73): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@440687c8

08-29 17:44:58.383: WARN/ActivityManager(73): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43fc9668 com.a8a.todolist/.ToDoList}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohan is right, inside Eclipse you open the DDMS perspective, you'll see a tab called "Logcat" which contains all the printed logs and includes also a detailed stacktrace of the exception which caused the Force Close popup to appear.

You miss probably the the "`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`" in your onCreate method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);

        ...
    }
```

Comment: This is what the logcat shows, not really understanding it much though as its my first time :p

Comment: Wow thank you!  So here's what happened...

i had     public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
because the tutorial had "Bundle icicle" not sure why, or what that even means, and when i put in "savedInstanceState" it errored, but once I changed it to  "super.onCreate(icicle);" it worked no problem

Answer (score 0):

Check out the logcat to see the error...it would be displayed against your package name in red color....This is the only method to check the Force Close type of errors....